# Fast reconnection to WLAN

Tags: wireless, 18.04

After losing WLAN connection, I want to reconnect.  So I want to switch WLAN off and on again. How can I do this quickly in 18.04?

Up to 14.04 I did this by clicking on the WLAN sign in the top bar and pressing <kbd>w</kbd> to switch off, and the same again to switch it on.

In 18.04 however, this much more laborious. Is there a simple way for doing this in 18.04?

Comment: Are you trying to solve a network problem? Why do you need/want to do this? Maybe we can help. You should just be able to select the desired wireless network again and it should reconnect, even if it's already connected.

Comment: @heynnema: Q1: Up to 14.04 I just clicked twice as explained above and never considered this "a network problem" as it does not happen everywhere and anytime. Q2: I want to be connected to the internet. And, no, it is not sufficient to just connect. I need to disconnect first - also in 18.04

Comment: You have a network problem because you say "After losing WLAN connection". Are you saying that you see a "?" where the network icon should appear? It sounds like this occurs on multiple different networks, yes? If you reselect the desired wireless network, don't you see it disconnect, then reconnect? Do you have a function key for airport mode, or wireless enable/disable, or a hard swtich?

Comment: See if https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/904/disconnect-wifi/ can do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a `bash` script to handle this exact problem. You can get `net-o-matic` from https://github.com/waltinator/net-o-matic.git - Watch for (WiFi) network going down, then do a user-specified thing to fix it.

```
walt@bat:~(0)$ net-o-matic --help
net-o-matic [-h|--help] [-v|--verbose] <config.file> 

Monitor the wireless network, and when it goes down, Do The
Next Thing (as specified by the <config.file>), to bring
the wireless net up.

The <config.file> contains #comments, blank lines, AND
single line commands, of your choice, to correct the
wireless network down condition. The first command in the
<config.file> will be executed the first time the net goes
down (or if the net is down when net-o-matic begins), the second
command will be executed the next time the net goes down,
and so forth, wrapping around at the end. The number of
single line commands in the <config.file> is unlimited.
walt@bat:~(2)$
```

Comment: This requires a `config.file`, right? Which one?

Comment: An example `net-o-matic.conf` comes with it.

Comment: You can call the "config file" anything you like, this is Linux. Invoke it with `net-o-matic MyFavouriteConfinFileName` if you like. The "config file" contains single line to "fix the connection" or "call a script to fix the connection. In the example `net-o-matic.conf` you'll see `nmcli con up id Nick` and `nmcli con up uuid 886ee877-a13c-43c0-a491-9de17f7fb55e`, but it could also use `/home/walt/bin/DoTwoThings`.